# Reactjs problem with map and using API, browser didnt show anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a problem using API, i try to show the name on API contacts into 
web browser

this is my code

**NewMain**

```
// import logo from './logo.svg';
// import './App.css';
// import List from './listapps/List.js'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(variable) {
    super(variable)
    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json)
      .then(data => this.setState({ items: data.items }))
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{
          items && items.map((item, index) =>
            <li key={index} >{item.name}</li>
          )
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

and i get blank, if i delete `items&&`

i got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at App.render (NewMain.js:25)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18470)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18423)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:20186)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:336)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:385)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:440)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:25780)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24695)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:24671)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24270)
    at react-dom.development.js:12199
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:697)
    at runWithPriority$2 (react-dom.development.js:12149)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:12194)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:12182)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23709)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:13994)
    at App.push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:325)
    at NewMain.js:15
```

what i want is to get the data and fill the data into list in `<li>` and then cjust reusable the list so i can look at it, but i can't get it right

so how can i solve it?

Comment: What you have looks correct. Have you checked the response of the fetch to ensure an error hasn't occurred (i.e. `.catch` on the promise chain)? Your initial state is an empty renderable array, so perhaps `data.items` doesn't have the shape you expect.

Comment: I don't know if it is a typo but first `.then` should be like this `then(response => response.json())` Notice the `()` at the end of the `json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `componentDidMount` method change `response.json` to `response.json()`. Also, the reason you are getting this error is because there is no `items` property in the `data` response object since it is just an array of objects. So, the right code should be:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ items: data }))
```

Comment: Beat me by 12 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`response.json` is a function and needs to be called like this `response.json()`

following is correct code

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>console.log(data)|| this.setState({ items: data }))
 }
```

[See it on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-wescoff-cwo70)